# Connect to a SQL Server database if java connection settings are known

Tags: sql, sql-server

My java project properties file has:

```
connectionString=jdbc:sqlserver://some-name:1433;databaseName=dbName;...
userName=someUserName
password=password //different one
```

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance.

Login should be "someUserName" and password should be "password". But what should go to server name? It should be some part of connectionString, but which one?

Comment: if you go to connectionstings.com you can build it out.

Comment: server name is `some-name,1433`. You may need to experiment a little. Note comma `,` before port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Server: Database engine
Server name: some-name
Authentication: SQL Auth
login : someUserName
passowrd:  password

Answer (score -1):

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true

That's the typical connection url.

Comment: I just can't see how this addresses the question.

Comment: I just thought if you asked what typical MySQL connection URL looks like. Sorry if my answer doesn't help!!!!